# Whitelist ip's which can access my Raspberry Pi port forwarded application

Tags: networking, security, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I have a small Angular project running on my Raspberry Pi. Through DuckDNS and port forwarding, I've opened it up for remote access through HTTP port 80. I would like to create an IP whitelist of IPs that can access this site.

What would be the best place to do this? Server level? Raspberry Pi level or Angular/Node js level? I've been looking in my server for port forward settings but it does not seem to have anything regarding IP whitelisting for port forwarding so the next best place would be Raspberry Pi level.

What would be the best and safest way to set this up on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it via iptables on your pi. Assuming port 80 is already open to the world:

`ufw allow from #.#.#.# to any port 80`

or

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s ip1,ip2,ip3 -j ACCEPT`

if you are concerned about security of web facing applications, and would prefer not to limit to specific IP addresses, you might want to consider something like `fail2ban` which will allow you to control failed login attempts and thwart persistent attackers.